# Timed event versus mouse event

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, setinterval

The following script was setup to be triggered by a jQuery `mouseenter` event but now needs to be triggered upon initial page scroll and re-run every 10 seconds without any interaction by the user. Much to my dismay I've not been able to create a working version with these specs.

I suspect I need to use javascript intervals but I'm not getting it right.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
function calcPoint(x1, y1, degrees, dist) {
    var radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    var x2 = Math.round(x1 + (Math.sin(radians) * dist));
    var y2 = Math.round(y1 + (Math.cos(radians) * dist));
    return [x2, y2];
}

var $cont  = $('#bubbles');
var $items = $cont.find('li');
var distance = 500; // distance for the items to travel
var duration = 750; // milliseconds
var delay    = 10000; // milliseconds

var explode = function() {
    $items.each(function(i) {
        var $item = $(this);

        // store the original position
        var pos = $item.position();
        if ($item.data('starting') == undefined) {
            $item.data('starting', pos);
        }
        //

        var angle = Math.floor(Math.random()*(360 + 1));
        var dest = calcPoint(pos.left, pos.top, angle, distance);
        $item.animate({
            left: dest[0],
            top:  dest[1],
            opacity: 0,
        }, duration);
    });
};

$cont.one('mouseenter', explode);

$cont.mouseleave(function() {
    $items.each(function() {
        var $item = $(this);
        var dest = $item.data('starting');
        $item.animate({
            left: dest.left,
            top: dest.top,
            opacity: 1
        }, duration);
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        $cont.one('mouseenter', explode);
    }, delay);
});
```

Comment: setInterval is really not that complex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function(){
    $cont.trigger('mouseenter');    
}, 10000);
```

You could simply trigger the `mouseenter` event every 10 seconds...

http://api.jquery.com/trigger

Comment: It's a little bit hacky, but it saves you from fiddling with your original code...

Answer (score 0):

If you want it even shorter - the plugin "jquery-timing" allows the following syntax:

```
$cont.repeat(10000).trigger('mouseenter');
```

Comment: jQuery-timing looks sweet. Thanks for the tip.